# How to do an exponential regression model?

Tags: r, regression, exponential, nls

I have a small [data base](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/df7fff0c4de20cca0e714d661fff36d220210201225540/93f003) (txt file).

I want to obtain an exponential regression in R.

The commands that I am using are:

```
regression <- read.delim("C:/Users/david/OneDrive/Desktop/regression.txt")
View(regression)
source('~/.active-rstudio-document', echo=TRUE)
m <- nls(DelSqRho ~ (1-exp(-a*(d-b)**2)), data=regression, start=list(a=1, b=1))
y_est<-predict(m,regression$d)
plot(x,y)
lines(x,y_est)
summary(m)
```

But, when I run it, I get an error:

```
Error in nls(DelSqRho ~ (1 - exp(-a * (d - b)^2)), data = regression,  : 
  step factor 0.000488281 reduced below 'minFactor' of 0.000976562
```

and I do not know how to solve it, how to obtain the exponwential regression, **please, any hint?**

Comment: ... In this case you can get an idea for starting parameters by fitting `start_m = lm(log(1/(1-DelSqRho)) ~ poly(d, 2, raw=TRUE), regression)` (this is your model equation rearranged) and getting `a = coef(start_m)[3]` and `b = sqrt(coef(start_m)[1]/coef(start_m)[3])`

Comment: @user20650 Thank you for your answers but I did not get them properly, I tried `start_m = lm(log(1/(1-DelSqRho)) ~ poly(d, 2, raw=TRUE), regression);;;;;;
y_est<-predict(start_m,regression$DelSqRho)` and I got `Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : 
    numeric 'envir' arg not of length one`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nls` is quite sensitive to the values of the starting parameters and so you want to choose values that give a reasonable fit to the data (`minpack.lm::nlsLM` can be a bit more forgiving).

You can plot the curve at your starting values of `a=1` and `b=1` and see that it doesn't do a great job of capturing the curve.

```
regression <- read.delim("regression.txt")
with(regression, plot(d, DelSqRho, ylim=c(-3, 1)))
xs <- seq(min(regression$d), max(regression$d), length=100)
a <- 1; b <- 1; ys <- 1 - exp(-a* (xs - b)**2)
lines(xs, ys)
```

[image]

One way to get starting values is by rearranging the objective function.
`y = 1 - exp(-a*(x-b)**2)` can be rearranged as `log(1/(1-y)) = ab^2 - 2abx + ax^2` (here `y` must be less than one). Linear regression can then be used to get an estimate of `a` and `b`.

```
start_m <- lm(log(1/(1-DelSqRho)) ~ poly(d, 2, raw=TRUE), regression)
unname(a <- coef(start_m)[3]) # as `a` is aligned with the quadratic term
# [1] -0.2345953 
unname(b <- sqrt(coef(start_m)[1]/coef(start_m)[3]))
# [1] 2.933345
```

(Sometimes it is not possible to rearrange the data in this way and you can try to get a rough idea of the parameters by plotting the curves at various starting parameters. [`nls2`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nls2/index.html) can also do a brute force search or grid search over starting parameters.)

We can now try to estimate the `nls` model at these parameters:

```
m <- nls(DelSqRho ~ 1-exp(-a*(d-b)**2), data=regression, start=list(a=a, b=b))
coef(m)
#          a          b 
# -0.2379078  2.8868374
```

And plot the results:

```
# note that `newdata` must be a named list or data frame 
# in which to look for variables with which to predict.
y_est <- predict(m, newdata=data.frame(d=xs))
with(regression, plot(d, DelSqRho))
lines(xs, y_est, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

The fit isn't great and is perhaps suggestive that a more flexible model is required.

Comment: Thank you, I tried all, but the last block of commands do not work, it promp to me `Error in data.frame(d = xs) : object 'xs' not found`

Comment: Another.Chemist ; `xs` is defined in the first code block